# HHVM returns error 500

Tags: php, apache2, hhvm

currently i am trying to setup a hhvm server. PHP Applications works fine for me, hack lang php files not.

My local sandbox returns (every request in error.log):

```
[Fri Jun 20 15:31:43.725292 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 26542] proxy_util.c(1694): AH00925: initializing worker fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/hhvm.local/$1 shared
[Fri Jun 20 15:31:43.725314 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 26542] proxy_util.c(1734): AH00927: initializing worker fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/hhvm.local/$1 local
[Fri Jun 20 15:31:43.725325 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 26542] proxy_util.c(1785): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 26542 for (127.0.0.1)
```

My Apache Config:

```
<virtualhost *:80>

    # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases

    ServerAdmin admin@domain.de
    ServerName hhvm.local
    ServerAlias www.hhvm.local

    # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hhvm.local

    # Custom log file locations

    LogLevel debug
    #LogLevel warn

    ErrorLog /var/www/hhvm.local/log/errors.log
    CustomLog /var/www/hhvm.local/log/access.log combined

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/hhvm.local/$1

<Directory /var/www/hhvm.local>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride FileInfo  All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Apache (2.4) is running, HHVM Daemon (3.0) is running,

~$: hhvm index.hh

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>Hello World!<br />Running on HHVM version 3.1.0</body></html>
```

If i call "hhvm.local" the server response a 500 Internal Server Error.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Could anybody help me? :)

Comment: So I guess that you also have an *index.php* available in the web root folder?

Comment: Does it work with a regular php install? Do you have the file access rights set correctly?

Comment: Yep, that's the confusing point..

Comment: look at `/var/log/hhvm/error.log`

Comment: what helped you out?

Comment: @bdart, uhm it was a really long time ago, so i am not sure. I guess, it was an upgrade from the os itself, and also the HHVM version.. Just remember, it was really tricky.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you do `hhvm index.php`
- index.php with only a echo is enough

Does it ouput something?

Yes?
Try `service hhvm start`

At least at my setup hhvm did not always start on it's own ...

No?

Then you probably have an install issue. There are 2 ways to install HHVM on ubuntu
- [self compiling](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Ubuntu-14.04)
- [pre built](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Prebuilt-packages-on-Ubuntu-14.04)

I personly use the pre built. At least the is the way I got it working :)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your ProxyPassMatch isn't set up to sniff out hh file extensions. You should use the following instead...

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.(hh|php)(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/hhvm.local/$1
```